# ie9 hack @root for less

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, less

In normal CSS, the below code is working

```
:root #element { color:pink \0/IE9; }
```

But how can I write it in LESS, which the targeted class is few layers below?

```
Level 1{
   Level2{
      Level3{
      /*IE 9 hack here*/
      }
   }
 }
```

If I added the @root on Level, the @root would appear on each and every Level3 and Level 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use & to reference the parent

e.g.

```
Level3 {
    :root & {
    }
}
```